# Detecting Mobile traffic on website

Tags: device-detection

Ok here we go I will try to make this as clear as I can.

I have made a website that can be view very clearly with any phone, tablet and, computer; I am about to have an app. What I have been looking for with no luck whatsoever is how can I prompt mobile devices about my app? I was hoping to maybe have a window come up saying we have an app get it now button or a continue on button which leads to our full site, trouble I am having is every mobile detection script I have found only detects so far as I can tell and I can't seem to get it to send the mobile users one way and the computers another (scripts were php) another was jquery but when I viewed the site with the mobile browser is was all crazy looking because I had  to get the jquery to work as a redirect.

Next issue is I have not the slightest idea how to or were to send a user for the app. a perfect example of what I want to do is at http://www.bankofamerica.com but I want to continue button to go to the full site.

Hope this was not to long winded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok for anyone who want to know this is the best option I can find and by far the least annoying to users.

download: https://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/

and write this in your page or however you wish to do it. I use a mix of my own and bootstrap styling on my webpages for the classes.

`<?php if($detect->isIOS()) : ?>`

`<div class="alert alert-block alert-success" id="mobileApp" style="position:absolute; left:10px; top:15px; z-index:1003; width:910px; text-align:center;">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">Close</button>
  <div class="span3"><img src="imgs/if.png" width="125" height="125"></div> <div class="span5"><h3>we are on the go!</h3></div>`

`<div class="row"> 
 <div class="span4"><h4>Download our app TODAY!</h4>` 

`<a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-large " style="color:#fff;">`Download iPhone App
`</a>`
 `</div>`

`</div>` 
`</div>`

`<?php endif; ?>`

you can repeat this for the android with

```
<?php if($detect->isAndroidOS()) : ?>
```